# Google Spreadsheet Dropdown Filter

Tags: drop-down-menu, filter, google-sheets

I have Google spreadsheet with a list of names in a column. (EX: David, Daniel, John, Cooper).
I made a drop down list of those names. Lets say I two more columns with Age and Birthday.

I want to show the age and birthday column information pertaining to 'David' when I choose 'David' from the drop down list.

A drop down list acting as a 'in spreadsheet filter'.

Any way to do this?

Ive tried the =FILTER() and =UNIQUE() but they don't quite get me what I want. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the drop down list in cell A1 (of sheet 2) and the columns with data are in sheet1
col A names
col B  age
col C  birthday

in cell B1 (of sheet2)

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:C, "Select B, C where A = """&A1&""" ", 1)
```